# Typescript mapping an array of objects to string array how to check for undefined

Tags: typescript

I've got a array of json objects called **projections** that I'm mapping to a array of strings based off a parameter of that object  called name.  How can I do a null or undefined check in the line of code below.

```
this.projections = this.cartService.outputProjections;
this.results = this.projections.map(a => a.name);
```

There's a few of these objects that have the a.name as undefined.

Comment: If the result comes from a server, it won't have any undefined, since it's not supported in JSON.

By the way, you could use the filter function to remove falsy elemnts: filter(a => !!a)

Comment: Christian there are a few that undefined values for a.name could you give an example?

Comment: @CristianTraìna Actually, if the property is not present in the JSON, when you attempt to access the property, it will return undefined (e.g., in `var o = JSON.parse('[{ "name": "value" }, {}]');`, `o[1].name === undefined`).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes, I wrote the comment before the `map` was added :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `filter` function after `map`, in order to remove falsy elements:

```js
var x = [1, 2, 'a', 'b', null, 'c', undefined];

x = x.filter(a => !!a);

console.log(x);
```

This will remove all the falsy elements, for example, also empty strings. If you want just to remove `null` and `undefined`, you can try this:

```js
var x = [1, 2, 'a', 'b', null, 'c', undefined, ''];

x = x.filter(a => typeof a !== 'undefined' && a != null);

console.log(x);
```